# How to load spring HTTPInvoker to jetty in test?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, embedded-jetty

I have googled this one but no luck. I just want to see the example of how to load all the services I need in embedded-jetty to be able to test in JUnit. So, my goal would be something like this.

```
private String url = "SERVICE_URL";

@Before
public void before() {
   // start jetty with all the services I need
}

@Test
public void shouldDoSthIWant() {
   // invoke SERVICE_URL and test.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample app found here shows how to run HttpInvoker using embedded jetty in a simple java app. You should be able adapt that code to make it work in a junit.
http://code.google.com/p/jianwikis/wiki/SpringHttpRemotingWithEmbeddedJettyServer

Reproducing relevant sections of the code / configuration from that pare down here

```
Server server = new Server();
SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(port);

Context context = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);

DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
dispatcherServlet.setContextConfigLocation("classpath:com/mycompany/config/DefaultServlet-servlet.xml");

ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet);
context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*")
```

DefaultServlet-servlet.xml

```
<!-- This default handler takes care of each of the services enumerated below -->
<bean id="defaultHandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

<bean id="helloService" class="com.mycompany.service.impl.HelloServiceImpl"/>

<!-- SpringHTTP Service Exposure -->

<bean name="/HelloService"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="service" ref="helloService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface"
            value="com.mycompany.service.iface.HelloService" />
</bean>
```